# The domain of lsc convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis

How to see that $int(dom(f)) \neq \emptyset$ where $f$ is a proper convex lower semi-continuous function from a Banach space to $\mathbb{R} \cup \{+\infty\}.$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}+\infty&\text{for }x\ne 0\\0&\text{for }x=0\end{cases}$$ is proper convex lsc function while its domain is a singleton $\{0\}.$

Comment: Thank you szw1710. Can we add more assumptions to have the result?

Comment: On $\Bbb R$ let $f(x_1),f(x_2)$ be finite. Then convexity itself implies that $f$ is finite on the interval $(x_1,x_2)$. Do you have any context for the question you originally asked? This could be helpful to find sufficient conditions.

Comment: Thank you szw1710. It was a comment from my professor. I think it was just an assumption he made.

Comment: The assertion holds for any upper semicontinuous function, not necessarily convex. Namely, if $-\infty<f(x_0)<+\infty$, then $f(x)\le f(x_0)+\varepsilon$ on a neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Comment: Nice observation szw1710. Thanks.